JAVA Apache POI does not detect certain patterns in a Microsoft Word document
I'm encountering an issue with Apache POI where it fails to detect certain templates within a Word document, while it detects others fine.
Undetected templates remain unchanged in the output document.
This is my code:
@Override
public byte[] generateSingleScale(SingleScale singleScale) {
    // Getting file

    try {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(wordFile));

        for (XWPFTable table : doc.getTables()) {
            for (XWPFTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
                for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                    for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                        String text = paragraph.getText();

                        if (text != null) {
                            // Conditional replacements


                            if (text.contains("[controlType]")) {replaceText(paragraph, "[controlType]", singleScale.getControlType());
                                }
                                if (text.contains("[owner]")) {replaceText(paragraph, "[owner]", singleScale.getOwner());
                                }
                                if (text.contains("[serialNumber]")) {replaceText(paragraph, "[serialNumber]", jednodelnoMerilo.getSerialNumber());
                                }

                            // More conditional replacements
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Rest of the code

        return workingDocumentBytes;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private void replaceText(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String placeholder, String replacement) {
    for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns()) {
        String text = run.getText(0);
        if (text != null && text.contains(placeholder)) {
            run.setText(text.replace(placeholder, replacement), 0);
        }
    }
}

For example, it will nicely replace the owner and serial number, but not the type of control.
I checked that there are no errors in word by doing CTRL + F and copy-paste template and it finds everything without problems.
These are the dependencies I used:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.5</version>
</dependency>

I'm using Word 2010 if that makes any difference.
I tried to implement the code differently, to change the template to something else and checked the size and font of the template in the document.

I don't know if it makes a difference, but what Java version are you using? Also, are you on Windows? Are you sure that text.contains("[controlType]") returns "true"?

I am on Windows 11, using Java 17. It does return true for most cases, but for some it does not.
